# Python ValueError: unknown url type: space (?)

Tags: python, urllib2, download

I am using the urllib2 module in Python 2.7 using Spyder 3.0 to batch download text files by reading a text file that contains a list of them:

```
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    with open('ocean_not_templated_url.txt', 'r') as text:
        lines = text.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            url = urllib2.urlopen(line.strip('ïÃ¯Â»Â¿ \xa0\t\n\r\v'))
            with open(line.strip('\n\r\t ').replace('/', '!').replace(':', '~'), 'wb') as out:
                for d in url:
                    out.write(d)
```

I've already discovered a bunch of weird characters in the urls that I've since stripped, however, the script fails when nearly 90% complete, giving the following error:

[image]

I thought it to be a non-breaking space (denoted by \xa0 in the code), but it still fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's an odd URL!**

Specify the communication protocol over the network. Try prefixing the URL with `http://` and the domain names if the file exists on the WWW.

Files always reside somewhere, in some server's directory, or locally on your system. So there must be a network path to such files, for example:

`http://127.0.0.1/folder1/samuel/file1.txt`

Same example, with *localhost* being an alias for *127.0.0.1* (generally)

`http://localhost/folder1/samuel/file1.txt`

That might solve the problem. Just think about where your file exists and how it should be addressed...

---

**Update:**

I experimented quite a bit on this. I think I know why that error is raised! :D

> I speculate that your file which stores the URL's actually has a **sneaky** *empty line* near the end. I can say it's near the end as you said that it executes about 90% of it and then fails. So, the python urllib2 function get_type is unable to process that empty url and throws `unknown url type:`

I think that's the problem! Remove that empty line in the file `ocean_not_templated_url.txt` and try it out!

Just check and let me know!  :P

Comment: Hmm.. where should I specify the protocol? Thanks for the suggestion, by the way.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed answer!! The prefix `http://` already exists on the list of URLs in the text file, e.g., `http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/paleo/paleocean/sediment_files/complete/e49-23-tab.txt`. (They are on an ftp server.) Is it possible that _if_ some of those URLs aren't used anymore that this is causing the problem? I know they've been moved around by our data managers, and some are quite old. Thanks again.

Comment: @SamuelLockshin-NOAAAffilia Updated it again! Hope I got it right!

Comment: Yes, there were some empty lines, and another issue was that there were two urls on one line, so the space between them tripped python up (although trying to read both as one url would have made it fail, too). Anyway, I marked the answer and update as correct. Thanks again! -Sam

Comment: @Samuel Yay! Glad to help!  :)